# R program to calculate some stats

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with data organized in 16 columns: first with names second with dates the other 14 with metrics.

Like:

```
      name  date hight weight ....
      John  1950 1.81  78
      John  1948 1.60  60
      Susan 1985 1.40  40    .
      Susan 1995 1.45  60
```

I want to perform some basic stats (mean, sd, etc) for each name, ie: mean of John's height, weight etc; mean of Susan, height, weight, etc.

In order to do so, first I wrote a function:

```
 mysummary <- function(x){
  setNames(c(mean(x), sd(x), skewness(x), kurtosis(x)),
           c("Mean", "SD", "Skewness", "Kurtosis"))
}
```

But when I execute it with the command:

```
    summaryStatic = by(data[,c('height','weight')], list(data$name),  function(x){
  y <- sapply(x, FUN =mysummary(as.numeric(x)))
  return(y)
})
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error in mean(x) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I know that is somewhat related with the `data.frame` structure. as you see I tried to solve it with `as.numeric(x)` but it didn't work.

Comment: How is possible you have a `matrix` made by character, dates and numbers??? Do you have a `data.frame` or a matrix with ONLY characters containing only number and dates (but coerced to char) ?

Comment: Please improve your question - it is not well structured and somehow unfocused. This makes it hard to follow, and especially answer it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. A data matrix... I have a .txt file, and to read it I used the read.delim function.

Comment: Learn some proper terminology and most of this problem will solve itself.

Comment: It might help if you posted the first five rows of the first five columns of the data set and the R code you are using.  Regardless, I usually use `read.table` or `read.csv`.  Maybe add `na.strings = "NA"`.  Maybe trying searching with Google for `read.table` examples.

Comment: a `data.matrix` !?! So how is possible you have " first with names second with dates " ? From `?data.matrix` : `Return the matrix obtained by converting all the variables in a data frame to numeric mode`. If so you I'd suggest you stick with `data.frame` and to help understand post the result of `head(yourtable)`

Comment: Thank you all!! I will re-edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but perhaps this does what you want.  If so, just add more summary statistics:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
      name  date height weight
      John  1950 1.81  78
      John  1948 1.60  60
      Susan 1985 1.40  40
      Susan 1995 1.45  60
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

with(my.data, aggregate(height ~ name, FUN = function(x) c( SD = sd(x), MEAN = mean(x) ) ))

with(my.data, aggregate(weight ~ name, FUN = function(x) c( SD = sd(x), MEAN = mean(x) ) ))

with(my.data, aggregate(cbind(height, weight) ~ name, FUN = function(x) c( SD = sd(x), MEAN = mean(x) ) ))

   name  height.SD height.MEAN weight.SD weight.MEAN
1  John 0.14849242  1.70500000  12.72792    69.00000
2 Susan 0.03535534  1.42500000  14.14214    50.00000

with(my.data, aggregate(my.data[,3:4], by = list(name), FUN = function(x) c( SD = sd(x), MEAN = mean(x) ) ))

  Group.1  height.SD height.MEAN weight.SD weight.MEAN
1    John 0.14849242  1.70500000  12.72792    69.00000
2   Susan 0.03535534  1.42500000  14.14214    50.00000
```